# Pull out values from a multidimensional array into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-xarray

I have a multidimensional dataarray with values at various lat, lon points. I would like to pull out these values and put them in a dataframe. I have tried using `DataArray.to_dataframe()` but I cannot get the dataframe to display exactly how I want it. Here is what the dataarray looks like.

```
<xarray.DataArray (lat: 109, lon: 327)>
array([[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       ...,
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]])
Coordinates:
  * lat      (lat) float64 -52.0 -51.0 -50.0 -49.0 -48.0 ... 53.0 54.0 55.0 56.0
  * lon      (lon) float64 28.0 29.0 30.0 31.0 32.0 ... 351.0 352.0 353.0 354.0
```

Ideal output would look like this:

```
Latitude   Longitude   Value
x          y           1
z          a           2
...        ...         ...
```

Is there a better way of doing this besides a dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

How about `to_pandas()`? This will give you a pandas dataframe, which should display in the way you are looking for.